# How to pause the application at a certain time in VBA

Tags: vba, date, time

The `Application.Wait()` in VBA allows the user to pause for a preset amount of time or pause until an exact time, like 10 AM, once encountered.

Is it possible to start the pause process at a certain time? For example, Let's say every 2 weeks I want to pause my process at 2 AM for 5 minutes no matter where it is in the module. I don't want to use

```vb
If(Now = "02:00:00") Then Application.wait(Now + TimeValue("00:05:00"))
```

since I am afraid it will miss the command if the process is somewhere else in the module.

Comment: There is no way to pause process without comparing current time to predefined time, unfortunatelly.

Comment: If you want to start a script at a certain time, please use `Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:29:00"), "msgbox 5" ` . During`Application.wait` the Excel freezes and the user cannot do anything.

Comment: You can call the .wait as the sub for ontime if you wish to hold still.